# Varnish: call vcl_pipe conditionally

Tags: varnish

It is my understanding, from looking at the [Varnish pipeline chart](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/states.html), that `vcl_pipe` can be only called from `vcl_recv`.

I am setting up a VCL to serve binary resources from a back end contingent on some conditions, including access control.

The way I thought of setting this up so far is thus: go through all my checks, which include moving out of `vcl_recv`; if the conditions are set for streaming the resource, set a flag; restart the transaction; check the flag first thing in `vcl_recv`, and if set, call `vcl_pipe`.

The only, major, issue is that I don't know how to set a flag (e.g. in `http.request`) that could not be forged by a request header. So a caller who knows my VCL could easily set the pipe flag and bypass all checks.

The other option is to keep all checks in `vcl_recv` but that may be clunky or even impossible.

Suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only, major, issue is that I don't know how to set a flag

You could unset it at the beginning of your `vcl_recv`, if number of restarts is zero (that would indicate "initial" landing in VCL e.g.

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        unset req.http.X-Foo; 
    }
```

Oh, and I found just [precisely what you were after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676091/how-to-reproduce-behavior-of-vcl-3-0-vcl-recv-restart-in-vcl-4-0) while getting the syntax for that :)

Comment: Thanks very much, also for the related thread. I think that should work, even if I restart for other reasons, if I add your snippet at the very beginning of my `vcl_recv`.